# How to copy a Vim macro to another Vim instance without clipboard support (i.e., no `+` register)?

Tags: macro

<sup>[Cross-posting from Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66585195/how-to-copy-a-vim-macro-to-another-vim-instance-without-clipboard-support-i-e/66586858#66586858) because I keep forgetting about this site...</sup>

Have a macro where a visually selected text will be made a markdown link and once the macro executes it leaves Vim in INSERT mode:

```
|  - VISUAL selection
i  - cursor position in INSERT mode
@l - invoke macro in "l" register

Some |text| saying stuff.   = @l => Some [text]() saying stuff.
                                                i
```

Register `l` holds the following:

```
:registers l
Type Name Content
  c  "l   S]%a()^Ohq<80>kb
```

Created it the following way:

0. Visually select some text
1. `q` then `l`
2. `S` then `]` ([`S` is a visual selection command in `vim-surround`](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround/blob/ca58a2d886cc18734c90c9665da4775d444b0c04/doc/surround.txt#L69-L73))

   ```
   ^ - normal mode cursor position

   |text|  =S]=>  [text]
                  ^
   ```
3. `%` (jump to closing bracket)
4. `a` and then type `()`
5. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd>
6. `h`
7. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd> then `q` (to finish the macro but to remain in INSERT mode)

So I selected this definition with the mouse (i.e., `*` register), and did `let @l = "S]%a()^Ohq<80>kb"` in the other Vim instance, resulting in

```
Some |text| saying stuff.   = @l => Some [text]()^Ohq<80>kb saying stuff.
                                                           i
```

It works if Vim is built with [clipboard support](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Accessing_the_system_clipboard#Checking_for_X11-clipboard_support_in_terminal) (`:let @+ = @l` in one Vim instance, and `:let @l = @+` in another), but I would like to learn the fundamentals of deciphering these representations.

UPDATE: There is a slight difference between the Vim representations of the recorded & clipboard-copied macros and the ones that are pasted manually: the sequences `^O` and `<80>` are highlighted as special in the former case, but the string is shown with uniform color in the latter.

The `l` is the original recorded macro, `+` is created by `:let @+ = @l`, and `c` content has been typed in verbatim:

[image]

---

Found a couple other Stackoverflow threads with a similar premise, but they weren't helpful:

#### [VIM macro editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6527456/vim-macro-editing)

Tried to convert the `^O` to `<C-O>` but it didn't work, and have no clue what `<80>kb` is.

Based on the creation steps above, I would have expected something like `S]%a()^Oh^Oq` instead of `S]%a()^Ohq<80>kb` anyway.

#### [Reliable solution to copy/paste Vim macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46947788/reliable-solution-to-copy-paste-vim-macros)

No replies, and based on what I understood, it is not applicable in my case.

#### [Saving vim macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024443/saving-vim-macros)

Chewed my way through the answers and comments, but no joy.

Answer (score 3):

The first Control-o has to be done with `<C-v><C-o>`; no idea about where the other bytes came from, but you can input the `<80>` with `<C-v>x80`.

On the other hand, macros in vim tend to be better-suited to interactive tasks. Once you want to start saving them, you'll need to either

- let them be saved via `viminfo` files (this is done automatically if you use the default `'viminfo'` setting, but you may need to set `viminfofile`?).
- create a mapping/function/etc., which is a little more robust for automation tasks, especially persistent tasks (I treat macros a little more ephemerally, since they can be clobbered by using the register for other things.)

So personally I would add the following to `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/markdown.vim` (since it looks you're creating markdown links):

```
xmap <buffer> <localleader>l S]%a()<C-o>h
```

- `xmap` for visual-mode excluding select-mode (`map` instead of `noremap` for recursive mappings—`S` is a plugin-provided mapping that we want to re-use here)
- `<buffer>` to keep it local
- `<localleader>l` how to invoke it (probably `\l` with a default configuration)
- `S]%a()<C-o>h` your mapping, without all the macro stuff in the way (and, benefit: it's easier to edit and read)

Answer (score 3):

### The explanation

D. Ben Knoble has given you a good alternative solution, and explained one way of setting the exact register contents with a `:let` command, but as you said you wanted to learn the fundamentals, I thought I'd add a little extra explanation.

As you noted, in the recorded macro, the `^O` and `<80>` are highlighted. This is because they are not simple sequences of multiple characters, but instead Vim's representation of "special characters". The `^O` is the ASCII SI (shift in) character, which can also be represented or typed as CTRL-O or the hex code `0x0f`.

`<80>` is hex `0x80`, but Vim in this instance Vim is using this as the first byte of `<80>kb`, which is its internal representation of a backspace.

You can add these to strings either by inserting them directly either by using <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> (as suggested by Ben), or by using Vim's [backslash escapes](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#expr-quote):

```
:echo "\<C-O>"
:echo "\x0f"
:echo "\<BS>"
:echo "\x80kb"
```

Like Ben, I'm very unclear why there are a q and a backspace in your recorded macro (I can't reproduce this when recording my own macro: could be something to do with your configuration). Regardless, it's obviously not necessary for your macro to insert a q and then immediately delete it, so one way of achieving your goal would be with the following `:let` command:

### The solution

```
:let @l = "S]%a()\<C-O>h"
```

Comment: Why there's a "q" => User wanted to end macro recording in Insert mode, so they typed "q" but that inserted a literal "q", then they used backspace to fix it (remove the "q") and finally used Ctrl-O + q to end the macro recording. That's my hypothesis. Yes, cleaning the macro not to include those two would be a great way to make the problem go away.

Comment: @filbranden :oooooh-emoji: